# How can I pass an array as an argument to a Rake task?

Tags: ruby, rake

I'm writing a Rake task and I want to pass an array as one of the arguments. Here's how I currently have it.

```
task :change_statuses, :ids, :current_status, :new_status do |task, args|
  puts "args were #{args.inspect}"
end
```

I've tried running the task these ways:

```
# First argument as array
rake "change_statuses[[1,2,3], active, inactive]"

# First argument as string
rake "utility:change_account_statuses['1,2,3', foo, bar]"
```

My **expected** output would be:

```
args were {:ids=> [1,2,3], :current_status=> 2 , :new_status=> 3}
```

However, my **actual** output in each case is:

```
args were {:ids=>"[1", :current_status=>"2", :new_status=>"3]"}
```

How can I pass an array to a Rake task?

Comment: I know I can use `ENV` for this, but I want to know if there's a more idiomatic way.

Answer (score 56):

One of the soulutions is to avoid `,` symbol in the string, so your command line would look like:

```
$ rake change_statuses['1 2 3', foo, bar]
```

Then you can simply split the IDs:

```
# Rakefile

task :change_statuses, :ids, :current_status, :new_status do |task, args|
  ids = args[:ids].split ' '

  puts "args were #{args.inspect}"
  puts "ids were #{ids.inspect}"
end
```

Or you can parse the ids value to get your expected output:

```
args[:ids] = args[:ids].split(' ').map{ |s| s.to_i }
```

I'm using rake 0.8.7

Comment: Note that when invoking a rake task with params, there should be no spaces after commas, else bash will misinterpret it and you'll get an error like `Don't know how to build task blahblah[param,'`. So the example above should read `rake change_statuses['1 2 3',foo,bar]
`

Comment: Thanks, Linus! Strange :) It really looks like a bash trick, but I remember I was testing it before posting the answer. The another approach to solve that problem is to put rake task into braces so the example will look like `rake "change_statuses['1 2 3', foo, bar]"`.

Comment: That works fine at the console, too, but I've gotten bitten when trying to run on heroku with both our suggestions. :) In the end, I had to type the equivalent of `heroku run rake "change_statuses['1 2 3',foo,bar]"`, since the outer quotes were dropped!

Comment: Thank you Linus for your comment!  Could not figure out why calling a task from the command line with multiple arguments was giving me this error "Don't know how to build task..." but you pointed me in the right (and simple) direction.

Comment: You can actually just call `.split` without any arguments and it'll default to splitting by a space (`" "`). This is what we went with by the way. Most clean we think, when the values cannot have spaces in them, like `id` values.

Answer (score 5):

You can also try to change the approach a little, and try to fetch ids with the `arg.extras` method.

```
$ rake change_statuses[foo, bar, 1, 2, 3]
```

```
task :change_statuses, [:foo, :bar] do |_task, args|
  puts args[:foo]     # => foo
  puts args[:bar]     # => bar
  puts args.extras    # => ["1","2","3"]
end
```

You can find more information in this article -> https://blog.stevenocchipinti.com/2013/10/18/rake-task-with-an-arbitrary-number-of-arguments/

Answer (score 3):

Another way to achieve this and also win the ability to pass a hash

```rb
namespace :stackoverflow do
  desc 'How to pass an array and also a hash at the same time 8-D'
  task :awesome_task, [:attributes] do |_task, args|
    options = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(args[:attributes])
    puts options
  end
end
```

And just call the rake task like this:

```
bundle exec rake "stackoverflow:awesome_task[what_a_great_key[]=I know&what_a_great_key[]=Me too\!&i_am_a_hash[and_i_am_your_key]=what_an_idiot]"
```

And that will print

```
{"what_a_great_key"=>["I know", "Me too!"], "i_am_a_hash"=>{"and_i_am_your_key"=>"what_an_idiot"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
rake "change_statuses[1 2 3, foo, bar]"
```

this works for me, you should not quota 1 2 3 with '

```
task :import_course, [:cids, :title] => :environment do |t, args|
  puts args[:cids]
end
```

if you quota 1 2 3 as the correct answer, args[:cids] will be "'1 2 3'", which `'` char included, you have to trim `'` char, but if you use my answer, args[:cids] will be "1 2 3", which is more easy to use, you just need args[:cids].split(" ") to get [1, 2, 3]

Comment: You have quoted the entire rake task, I think rake change_status['1 2 3', foo bar] is more appropriate.

Comment: have you tried? please try, rake change_status['1 2 3', foo bar], pass '1 2 3' as string, but include `'`, "'1 2 3'", you have to trim `'` char, rake change_status['1 2 3', foo bar] pass [1, 2, 3] as string without `'` char included, which is more easy to use, you just need to split(" ") to get array

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as an alternative:

```
 task :my_task, [:values] do |_task, args|
   values = args.values.split(',')
   puts values
 end
```

and run the task using

```
rake my_task"[1\,2\,3]"
```